# Remove Axis Numbers from STL Plot

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I need to remove the axis numbers from a plot of a "Seasonal Decomposition of Time Series by Loess" (stl).

```
a <- stl(myTimeseries, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)
plot(a,...
```

The following do not work:

```
plot(a, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
```

==> Numbers still shown

```
plot(a, axes=F)
```

==> Error in plot.ts(X[, i], type = if (i < nplot) "l" else "h", xlab = "",  : 
 formale argument "axes" fits to multiple given arguments 
(this is a translation)

Comment: Have you tried calling `par(xaxt="n")` before `plot`? I'm guessing it won't help as `plot.stl` seems to be ignoring your parameter on purpose, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: In fact that does work! Awesome